# SQL ORA-01843 not a Valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

> ```
> SQL> select Users.name , Users.surname , Users.email from Users
>   2  inner join  Login_History on Login_History.user_id=Users.user_id where
>   3  Login_History.entry_date=TO_DATE('01/12/2020','dd/mm/yyyy');
> Login_History.entry_date=TO_DATE('01/12/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')
>
> ERROR at line 3:
> ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ```

In the 3th line, I want to get results of where `Login_History.entry_date=01/12/20`
; however, it gives an invalid month error.

This code is in SQL/Plus.

By this way, I can reach some data in the tables .

Comment: I hope, Login_History.entry_date is a DATE column, not CHAR/VARCHAR

Comment: Date is stored in the system as “DD/MM/YYYY”, e.g., 01/12/2020

Comment: It is good, but what datatype has the column entry_date ?

Comment: You need to to_date login_history_date also.

Comment: I tried to use capital letters too , same result

Comment: If i replace , i get same error

Comment: Why do you continue to ignore repeated requests for the data type of LOGIN_HISTORY_DATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query works **IF** the `entry_date` column has the `DATE` data type; since it does not work then I am assuming that you are not using a `DATE` data type and are using a `VARCHAR2` data type for the column.

The best solution is to fix the table and store dates as `DATE` and not as a string:

```sql
ALTER TABLE login_history ADD ( entry_date2 DATE );
UPDATE login_history
SET entry_date2 = TO_DATE( entry_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
ALTER TABLE login_history DROP PRIMARY KEY; -- Assuming it is part of the primary key.
ALTER TABLE login_history DROP COLUMN entry_date;
ALTER TABLE login_history RENAME COLUMN entry_date2 to entry_date;
ALTER TABLE login_history ADD
  CONSTRAINT login_history__pk PRIMARY KEY ( user_id, entry_date );
```

Then your query will work without any changes.

---

Alternately, you can use `TO_DATE` to explicitly convert `entry_date` from a string to a `DATE`:

```sql
select Users.name,
       Users.surname,
       Users.email
from   Users
       inner join Login_History
       on ( Login_History.user_id=Users.user_id )
where  TO_DATE( Login_History.entry_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) = DATE '2020-12-01';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=453d1678475ed219bfb5652b3c964eb0)*

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest writing the query as:

```
select u.name, u.surname, u.email
from Users u join
     Login_History lh
     on lh.user_id = u.user_id
 where lh.entry_date = date '2020-12-01';
```

Note the use of table aliases and how the date constant is defined.

The above assumes that `entry_date` is actually stored as a `date`.  **If it is not, you should fix the data model.**  After all, dates should be stored as `date`s, not strings.

If it is not a date, but a string in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, then you can simply do an equality comparison:

```
where lh.entry_date = '01/12/2020'
```

This works for *equality*, but it will not work for most *ranges* -- because strings are the wrong way to store a date.

Comment: @MertÖzçelik . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?